# Game Theory Rulerette, Sprague-Grundy Theorem

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Here is the question:

> Rulerette. Suppose in the game Ruler, we are not allowed to turn over
>   just one coin. The rules are: Turn over any consecutive set of coins
>   with at least two coins being turned over, and the rightmost coin
>   going from heads to tails. Find the Sprague-Grundy function for this
>   game and relate it to the Sprague-Grundy function for Ruler.

So I understand what I'm suppose to be doing but when I do the calculations I am not getting the answer the book has written out. So I want to figure out what exactly I am doing wrong.

Here is what I am doing.

since the rule states that i need to turn over at least two coins,

g(x) = mex {g(x-1)+ g(x-2), g(x-1)+...+g(1)}

the + represents binary operation. What I'm getting stuck on is number 4 and 6.

working it out I get the following:

g(4) = mex{g(3)+g(2) = 0 +1 =1, g(3)+g(2)+g(1)= 0 + 1 + 0 = 1} so it should be 0, right?

but the table says 2. which I'm so confused about. Any help would be GREAT

Comment: So I noticed that when I include only g(x-1) in the mex as well it works, but doesn't that go against the rule of not being allowed to turn over just one coin? Or by including g(x-1) we're also making the assumption that we're turning or g(x)? and that is where I'm going wrong?

Comment: It would help to clarify the rules of the game further, since I assume most people are not familiar with Ruler.

Answer (score 0):

Ruler is described on page I-31 in [these notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etom/Game_Theory/comb.pdf), from Part I of [Thomas Ferguson's](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etom/) [Game Theory course](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etom/Game_Theory/Contents.html). Those notes had this useful context:

> ...we are given a finite number of coins in a row, each showing either heads or tails. A move consists of turning over...a set of coins...the rightmost coin turned over must go from heads to tails...
>
> to find the Sprague-Grundy value of a position, we only need to know the Sprague-Grundy values of positions with exactly one head...
>
> **Ruler.**...*Any number of coins may be turned over but they must be consecutive and the rightmost coin must be turned from heads to tails.* If we number the positions of the coins starting with $1$ on the left, the Sprague-Grundy function for this game satisfies $$g(n)=\mathrm{mex}\{0,g(n-1),g(n-1)\oplus g(n-2),\ldots,g(n-1)\oplus\cdots\oplus g(1)\}\text{.}$$

This question about Rulerette happens to appear in [homework 4](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Emlugo/stat155-f11/155-hw4.pdf) of [Michael Lugo](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Emlugo/)'s [Fall 2011 Game Theory course](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Emlugo/stat155-f11/). Michael is also [on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/173/michael-lugo).

---

The important thing to understand is where that formula for Ruler comes from, and then ww can use that understanding to tackle Rulerette. For instance, in Ruler:

$g(4)=g(\mathrm{TTTH})$
$=\mathrm{mex}\{g(\mathrm{TTTT}),g(\mathrm{TTHT}),g(\mathrm{THHT}),g(\mathrm{HHHT})\}$
$=\mathrm{mex}\{g(\mathrm{}),g(\mathrm{TTH}),g(\mathrm{THH}),g(\mathrm{HHH})\}$
$=\mathrm{mex}\{g(\mathrm{}),g(\mathrm{TTH}),g(\mathrm{TTH}) \oplus g(\mathrm{TH}), g(\mathrm{TTH}) \oplus g(\mathrm{TH}) \oplus g(\mathrm{H})\}$
$=\mathrm{mex}\{0,g(3),g(3)\oplus g(2),g(3)\oplus g(2)\oplus g(1)\}$

In Rulerette, we do not have the move to $\mathrm{TTTT}$, so we don't have the first $0$ in the $\mathrm{mex}$, as [the OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/240004/dean3794) noted. However, when $x\ge2$, we can still flip over $2$ coins (like the move to $\mathrm{TTHT}$), so the formula for Rulerette should still have $g(x-1)$ in it. For Rulerette, we have: $g(x)=\mathrm{mex}\{g(x-1),g(x-1)\oplus g(x-2),\ldots,g(x-1)\oplus\cdots\oplus g(1)\}$.

Thus, we have $g(1)=0$ (no moves available), $g(2)=\mathrm{mex}\{g(1)\}=1$, $g(3)=\mathrm{mex}\{g(2),g(2)\oplus g(1)\}=\mathrm{mex}\{1,1\oplus0\}=\mathrm{mex}\{1,1\}=0$, and then $g(4)=\mathrm{mex}\{g(3),g(3)\oplus g(2),g(3)\oplus g(2)\oplus g(1)\}=\mathrm{mex}\{0,0\oplus1,0\oplus 1\oplus 0\}=\mathrm{mex}\{0,1,1\}=2$.

Comment: The links to Michael Lugo's lecture notes are unfortunately broken. Do you have others ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I will ask Michael if he can rehost it, but I believe all the link was there for was just to prove that the question wasn't original/may have spread from his course. I don't think it had any other info to add to this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.